# AngularJs - how to get $http result

Tags: angularjs

I got a template written by angular but I am stuck with their programming style.
Here is some code

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular.module("app.tables", []).controller("tableCtrl", ["$scope", "$filter", "$http",     '$window', function ($scope, $filter, $http, $window) {
    var init;
    $window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', 111);
    $http.post('/api/getAdminUsers', {}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        //$scope.stores = data;
        $scope.stores = data.users;

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        alert(status);
    });
    return $scope.stores =[]
        , $scope.searchKeywords = "", $scope.filteredStores = [], $scope.row = "", $scope.select = function (page) {
        var end, start;
        return start = (page - 1) * $scope.numPerPage, end = start + $scope.numPerPage, $scope.currentPageStores = $scope.filteredStores.slice(start, end)
    }, $scope.onFilterChange = function () {
        return $scope.select(1), $scope.currentPage = 1, $scope.row = ""
    }, $scope.onNumPerPageChange = function () {
        return $scope.select(1), $scope.currentPage = 1
    }, $scope.onOrderChange = function () {
        return $scope.select(1), $scope.currentPage = 1
    }, $scope.search = function () {
        return $scope.filteredStores = $filter("filter")($scope.stores,     $scope.searchKeywords), $scope.onFilterChange()
    }, $scope.order = function (rowName) {
        return $scope.row !== rowName ? ($scope.row = rowName, $scope.filteredStores = $filter("orderBy")($scope.stores, rowName), $scope.onOrderChange()) : void 0
    }, $scope.numPerPageOpt = [3, 5, 10, 20], $scope.numPerPage = $scope.numPerPageOpt[2], $scope.currentPage = 1, $scope.currentPageStores = [], (init = function () {
        return $scope.search(), $scope.select($scope.currentPage)
    })()
}])
```

I want to get data from $http and but this programming style return all methods and variables to my controller. I did my http request but it seems not return the value to the $scope.stores . How can I put the .success listener into the return or is there any other good practical way?

Answer (score 0):

Because your controller doesn't have to return the interface. The interface is assigned to the $scope variable.

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular.module("app.tables", [])
       .controller("tableCtrl", ["$scope", "$filter", "$http",'$window', tableCtrl]; 

function tableCtrl($scope, $filter, $http, $window) {
    var init;
    $window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', 111);
    $http.post('/api/getAdminUsers', {})
         .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             //$scope.stores = data;
              $scope.stores = data.users;
         })
         .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            alert(status);
    });
    $scope.stores = [];
    $scope.searchKeywords = "";
    $scope.filteredStores = [];
    $scope.row = "";
    $scope.select = function (page) {
        var end, start;
        return start = (page - 1) * $scope.numPerPage, end = start + $scope.numPerPage,      $scope.currentPageStores = $scope.filteredStores.slice(start, end)
   };
   $scope.onFilterChange = function () {
       return $scope.select(1), $scope.currentPage = 1, $scope.row = ""
   };
   $scope.onNumPerPageChange = function () {
       return $scope.select(1), $scope.currentPage = 1
   };
   $scope.onOrderChange = function () {
       return $scope.select(1), $scope.currentPage = 1
   };
   $scope.search = function () {
       return $scope.filteredStores = $filter("filter")($scope.stores, $scope.searchKeywords), 
    $scope.onFilterChange()
   };
   $scope.order = function (rowName) {
       return $scope.row !== rowName ? ($scope.row = rowName, $scope.filteredStores = $filter("orderBy")($scope.stores, rowName), $scope.onOrderChange()) : void 0
   };
   $scope.numPerPageOpt = [3, 5, 10, 20];
   $scope.numPerPage = $scope.numPerPageOpt[2];
   $scope.currentPage = 1;
   $scope.currentPageStores = [];
   (init = function () {
       return $scope.search(), $scope.select($scope.currentPage)
   })()
})
```

There's a lot to say about your code. But I'm just gonna leave it to solve your current problem.